# Problem with array multidimensional with CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, https, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a problem sending the multidimensional array by curl, when I send it I receive this result:

Required parameter 'definitionKey' is missing "," errorcode ": 10002," documentation ":" "

Could you tell me what is my mistake?

this is the code I have:

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token; // Prepare the authorisation token    
echo $authorization;

//The data you want to send via POST
$fields = array (
'definitionKey' => 'pruebacondata',
'status'=> 'active',
'name'=> 'Mi prueba con data extension',
'description'=> 'Created via REST',
'classification'=> 'Default Transactional',
'content'=> array (
    'customerKey'=> 'ro-prueba'
),
  'subscriptions'=> array (
    'list'=> 'Lista para envios de prueba',
    'dataExtension'=> 'prueba_ro',
    'autoAddSubscriber'=> true,
    'updateSubscriber'=> true
  ),
  'options'=> array  (
    'trackLinks'=> true,
    'cc'=> '[prueba@t.mx]',
    'bcc'=> '[prueba@t.mx]'
  )
  );
  //url-ify the data for the POST
 $fields_string = json_encode($fields);

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization, 
 'Content-Length: 0' )); // Inject the token into the header

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
 //So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

the url variable is not published for security reasons

thanks

Comment: What happens if you send it without doing `$fields_string = json_encode($fields);` ?

Comment: It would be worth doing two things:  1) Try logging out `$fields_string` and then manually plugging that into the curl command.  (I'd guess, if anything, your json encoding is adding square brackets because it's an array, and maybe salesforce doesn't like that, but having it as a string you can manipulate lets you try a few thins).  2) add to the question _which_ salesforce API you're calling, because they have different requirements, e.g. `getSendDefinition` requires `definitionKey` in the URL.